# Fortran Command Line Input In Specification Part

Tags: fortran, initialization, user-input

I am new to fortran and I am having issues trying to pass in a argument via command line. For instance my working code has the following lines:

```
!experimental parameters
real (kind=8), parameter :: rhot                =1.2456
!density of top fluid
real (kind=8), parameter :: rhob                = 1.3432
!density of bottom fluid
real (kind=8), parameter :: rhof                = (rhot-rhob)
!generic function of rhot rhob
```

And I would like to hand them in via:

```
./fulltime_2009_05_15_Fortran9 [Value rhot] [Value rhob]
```

using something like:

```
call get_command_argument(1,input1)
call get_command_argument(2,input2)
read(input1,*) rhot
read(input2,*) rhob
```

The issue is, I declare parameters like rhof that depend on the inputted values. So I would like to have the user inputted values applied immediately so that all dependent parameters can use those values. However, if modify my code to be:

```
real (kind=8) :: rhot,  rhoB
call get_command_argument(1,input1)
call get_command_argument(2,input2)
read(input1,*) rhot
read(input2,*) rhob
real (kind=8), parameter :: rhof    = (rhot-rhob)
```

I get the error: A specification statement cannot appear in the executable section.

Any thoughts or suggestions for how I could address this issue?

Comment: If you are new to Fortran, do not learn `kind=8`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Comment: Why do you need `rhof` to be a `parameter`?

Comment: @VladimirF I am modifying a large code that I didn't create. So the original creator was using that and it pops up in numerous places. Sounds like it could cause issues, but I am afraid to remove it from the 20+ cases it pops up. Do you recommend I should?

Comment: @veryreverie Not sure. I honestly don't understand why I would ever specify it as a parameter as opposed to a assignable variable (not sure if I am saying that right). For instance, I am not sure why I don't always just write:
real (kind=8) :: rhof    = (rhot-rhob) ?

Comment: @FluidMan the `parameter` keyword means that a variable is constant and known at compile time. See e.g. [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vnaj/index.html). If you want to set `rhof` at runtime, then you don't want this.

Comment: Pi would be an example of a parameter. And the A=Pi*R^2 would have R as an input variable and A as a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A compile time constant (`parameter`) cannot be changed by command line arguments. It is fixed at compile time.

This code:

```
real (kind=8) :: rhot,  rhoB
real (kind=8) :: rhof
call get_command_argument(1,input1)
call get_command_argument(2,input2)
read(input1,*) rhot
read(input2,*) rhob
rhof    = (rhot-rhob)
```

would compile fine. But you cannot have a variable declaration after a normal statement.

You could have

```
real (kind=8) :: rhot,  rhoB
call get_command_argument(1,input1)
call get_command_argument(2,input2)
read(input1,*) rhot
read(input2,*) rhob

block
  real (kind=8) :: rhof    = (rhot-rhob)
```

in Fortran 2008, but you cannot define a compile-time constant using a non-constant expression.

Some programming langauges do allow a type of constants that are set during the configuration of the run and are fixed thereafter. Fortran is not one of them.